# Which is really immutable in redux data or state or both?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I always read that state in redux is and should be immutable, while logging store.getState() will return the state which may represent a modified data after dispatching a certain action.

This part is confusing to me, how we can consider state is immutable in this case, do state here refer to the original data or the initial data that passed as the first argument to the reducer??

```
const reducer = (state = [], action) => {


}
```

Is the immutable state here the initial state which is an **empty** **array** or the data that dispatched after fetching???

I need some clarification about this confusing part???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The redux state itself is not immutable** but it is composed from immutable data structures. Saying that state is immutable is not correct.

The whole point of a data structure being immutable is that you never mutate it. When speaking about arrays, mutating means adding, removing or setting values (e.g. `push`, `shift`, `splice` etc). Therefore, to change a value, you always have to create a new array (instead of mutating the existing array).

For example:

```
const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
    const addedValue = action.payload.addedValue;
    return [...state, addedValue];
}
```

not

```
const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
    const addedValue = action.payload.addedValue;
    state.push(addedValue);
    return state;
}
```

In this sense both the previous state and the new state (the returned value) are both *immutable* data structures.

To explain the concept of timewalking mentioned in comments, first we suppose there is some redux state in some variable:

```
let state = /* redux state */
```

Whenever an action is triggered, all reducers run recursively to create a new state. The whole concept in Redux is expressed by something like this:

```
let oldState = state;
state = reducers(oldState, action);
```

The concept of timewalking means that we do something like this:

```
const stateHistory = [];
stateHistory.push(state)
state = reducers(oldState, action);
```

This way our `stateHistory` variable contains the complete previous state. To timewalk, we can simply:

```
state = stateHistory[index];
```

and rerender.

However, this wouldn't work without immutable data structures. Immutable data structures ensure that all states in history are independent and mutating one won't affect the rest.

Comment: Thanks , i understand all of that, but if the initial state is an empty array so our non-mutated original state would be an empty array, what is the point then to store an empty array??

Comment: @SaherElgendy Empty array is better than `null` or `undefined` because your app won't crash when you try to read its `length` or index it. That's the concept of prefering non-optional variables over optional variables (variables that can be `null`). The reason to use an empty array is specific to a given use case.

Comment: I think I don't understand you question then. An empty array is a valid value describing the situation when there are no items?

Comment: i agree that reducer takes date and return a new data so there is no mutability here, what confuses me is the sentence 'state is immutable' yes i know technically it is immutable but how this can make a difference, i can mutate it and nothing would happen, the previous state would disappear anyway!!

Comment: @SaherElgendy Using only immutable structures in state (which is a bit awkward in pure JS) has some very positive implications. For example, when checking whether a part of the state has changed, you can simply use `===` (object equality).  And that makes rerenders very fast because only the actually changed parts will have to rerendered (see `PureComponent`).

Comment: Dan abramove says that immutable state give us an advantage of time travel debugging, i could not understand this part, any way you can add your last comment to the original answer  so i can accept it. it was somehow helpful!

Comment: With immutable state you can hold state history in memory. With mutable states changing the state would destroy saved history. If you dont see it, try to implement it.

Comment: thanks, i could not imagine that this is possible, how can i implement saving state history, any resources for that??

Comment: @SaherElgendy Updated with a short explanation.

Comment: Thank you this makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

> I always read that state in redux is and should be immutable, while
>   logging store.getState() will return the state which may represent a
>   modified data after dispatching a certain action.

This is true.

> This part is confusing to me, how we can consider state is immutable
>   in this case, do state here refer to the original data or the initial
>   data that passed as the first argument to the reducer??

State as an argument of the reducer refers to the actual state. If it's the first time calling the reducer, then state will be initialized with the default value, in this case *[]*. This feature is called [Default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

> Is the immutable state here the initial state which is an empty array
>   or the data that dispatched after fetching???

Redux requires to write reducers as pure functions so that the state modifications are handled exclusively by Redux.

For more information please refer to [Reducer's documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers).

Comment: Thank you but this does not answer anything, i know that state would be what is returned from the reducer after a certain action, otherwise the default one will be returned, so our state data seems changing so from where come this fact " state in redux is immutable"

Comment: State should not be mutated by your code, it's modification is handled purely by Redux. Therefore it is said that state is immutable.